# Inverter Design - High Side MOSFET Switch-off Issue

Tags: mosfet, inverter

I've been chasing an issue in a 3-Phase BLDC inverter for some time now. The problem manifests itself as high current and voltage sense noise at high DC bus voltages, irrespective of the load on the inverter.

I've broken the design down into its smallest elements and from what I can tell, the voltage at the switching node (source of high side MOSFET) remains at the DC Bus voltage long after the high side MOSFET is off. This measured voltage is most likely stored energy in a bootstrap capacitor on my driver or the capacitance of the MOSFET.

When the low side MOSFET is switched on, I get fairly large oscillations at the low side gate and drain. This also appears as large currents in the current measurement system.

About the design:

1. 3-Phase BLDC Inverter, capable of 310V DC Bus, however for this exercise testing at 24VDC.
2. MOSFETS are [STF10N60DM2](https://www.st.com/en/power-transistors/stf10n60dm2.html)
3. Gate Driver is [6EDL04N06PT](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/gate-driver-ics/three-phase-drivers/6edl04n06pt/)
4. PWM Control, etc is generated from TMS320F28069F MCU

I've prepared an example schematic showing a a single pair of MOSFETS as per the image below, and I've annotated the colors of the scope measurement channels.

[image: Basic Schematic]

I've captured the relevant issue on the scope in the image below, however there are a few things to note.

1. Blue = Upper Gate measured at the MOSFET
2. Green = Upper Source Measured at the MOSFET
3. Pink = Lower Gate, Measured at the MOSFET
4. Yellow = Switching Node (Identical to Green but overlaid on Blue)
5. D4 = High side PWM Signal from MCU, D5 = low Side.

In this capture there is NO LOAD connected to the design, and the PWM is operating in open loop control mode.  I have very similar waveforms, irrespective of whether I have No Load, a Resistive Load or an Inductive Load connected.

There is a ~500ns propagation delay through the driver, the PWM dead-band is at 800ns and I've annotated with grey lines the PWM input versus MOSFET switching edge.

As for the probing techniques, I have SMA connectors on the hardware at the appropriate measurement points. Even if I use a standard scope probe and 100mm ground clip, I still get the same measurement. Using these two diverse measurement methods, and achieving the same measurements I'm certain the noise is present in the circuit and not a measurement artefact.

[image: Scope Capture 01]

What I have tried:

1. Ferrite beads in the gate drive path.
2. Various combinations of Gate slew control resistors
3. 1K resistor between GS on each FET
4. 100nF to 10uF bootstrap capacitors
5. Different types of MOSFETS

My Questions:

1. Is what I am seeing on the Yellow Trace (Switching Node) correct? I think I should see the yellow trace go low after upper MOSFET is off.
2. When the lower MOSFET switches on (Pink Trace) I get a lot of disturbance, (this is actually massive at 310VDC). What is the cause of this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 1, 2018-07-25:**

Top Layer Image showing gate driver, low side gate trace (its a 0.8mm track, ~35mm long). Pink and Yellow measurement points shown. Red triangles are gate driver GND attach points.
[image]

Bottom layer image showing FET's, DC Bus, GND and decoupling caps. Please note there are additional layers of copper in this design where GND and DC_BUS are duplicated, hence the via stitching.
[image]

Note:
In this design we are using our own current sense resistors on each phase, and NOT using the current trip feature of the gate driver. This means that Pin 12 and Pin 13 (VSS and COM) are linked together.

Comment: I know  you said you tried different loads. But with no load, there is no reason for the switch node to go low until the lowside FET turns on. I definitely don't like the gate waveform you are seeing on the low side.

Comment: @mkeith, yeah thanks, I should have clarified the no-load situation like you mentioned.

Comment: You say you expect the switch node to go low as soon as the high side gate is off. But that is not a correct expectation when there is no load. When both high side and low side are off, the switch node is floating. So it does not go low until the low side turns on.

Comment: The disturbance you see when the low-side switch turns on seems to be caused by the drain-gate capacitance of the low side FET interacting with some parasitic inductance. As the gate goes up, all is well. But as soon as it reaches what SHOULD be a plateau, it starts to ring or resonate. I think playing with the low-side gate elements might allow you to eliminate it. Try connecting the gate directly to the driver. They try resistor only (like 10 Ohms). Etc. You shouldn't need two resistors and a diode since your gate driver already has a dead time.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, I would suggest that you engage with Infineon field applications engineers (FAE). You obviously know what you are doing, and have formulated your question very thoroughly. I would think Infineon would be very interested in helping you.

Comment: @mkeith. Thanks. We had a previous issue with this brand of gate driver and the direct support was not very useful, I might try and find a local rep and make use of a FAE that way.  For the low side gate driver, I've mad some changes to the gate resistor, changed it up to 220R and there have been improvements overall.  This application is challenging because of space constraints, motor speed, thermal and voltage levels that I'm having to make lots of trade-offs.  The on/off resistor setup is to limit ringing irrespective of the gate driver dead time, is this your understanding too?

Comment: My understanding of the on/off resistor setup was that it was an effort to have asymmetric slew rates at the gate. So that turn-on experiences maximum drive, but turn-off experiences reduced drive. This can help build in dead time when the gates are driven simultaneously. But should not be needed for your gate driver because it implements its own dead time. At least, that is my understanding. I think I would try a direct connection (0 Ohms) from the gate driver to the gate on the low side and see how it looks.

Comment: I do see your point, though. With the open-circuit conditions, the ringing doesn't start until the low-side is turned on. But when there is load current, things will be different. Will the eventual load be a three-phase motor of some type?

Comment: @mkeith yes its a 1KW BLDC in the end application.  With 0R on the gates the FETS are uncontrollable with the amount of ringing. The board-layout is compact, but still has 35mm long, 0.6mm wide tracks from driver to gate, directly on top of a 0V plane. Lots of bypassing caps, solid ground plane, etc. I really feel the driver is playing a massive part in this overall problem as I've never experienced anything this bad before.

Comment: I see. My thinking was to lower the impedance looking from the gate into the driver. But it seems that what is needed is damping. The only other place I can think of to put a damper resistor for the low side is between VCC and the driver IC. You could try it. I read about that in a fairchild app note. But I have never done it.

Comment: Or put a resistor in series with the bootsrap cap. It could maybe be playing a role in the ringing.

Comment: Actually the curves are not too bad.  The driver has a typical 60-100 nS rise time which you see on the pink.  The peak on the pink occurs (as @mkeith says) due to the Drain-Gate capacitance; your drain voltage drops at a very high rate, and the downward voltage is coupled back to the gate, driving the gate voltage down (your driver IC only puts out 240 ma into a dead short, so its output impedance may be higher thqan the 10-ohm resistor).  The ringing is due to stray inductance in your layout; I'd like to see the layout, but I'm thinking retrun path.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead. Thanks. I've updated the post showing the top and bottom layer track work. I've made a note about not using the drivers current limit system (by not placing a sense resistor between VSS and COM of the driver). I'm not sure what effect has on the overall system. I am also now wondering about VSS and COM and if they need to be separated somehow?

Comment: Got too long winded so I will put my response in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a straight drive problem to me.  The gate and drain curves have a relationship that looks reasonable, so I think you are getting a good measurement.  The only thing to do is to decrease the drive impedance.  You can reduce the inductance in the gate drive lines by making the path as short and fat as possible; remove the coupling to the current path by keeping the gate drive path from laying on top of the power and ground planes; but to really improve you will have to get a more muscular driver to overcome the negative feedback from the gate-drain capacitance.  This symptom will become more pronounced with the higher voltage because the higher dv/dt will mean more voltage on the gate.  You can shop for a FET with low gate capacitances, but these generally have higher "on" resistance.

As I said earlier, this is not a terrible switching waveform; you can probably run a motor with moderate current but you will have losses that will heat up the FET.  However if you are running high currents, you have probably noticed that "real" gate driver IC's often sport output currents in the 5 ampere range.

One other thing you *must* do in any case is to provide a big low ESR (ceramic not electrolytic) decoupling cap for your drive circuitry.  There must be an adequate charge reservoir to provide that instantaneous ampere or two that you will need to overcome the dv/dt coupling effect.  I can't tell if you have a 2.2 uF ceramic from your schematic, but I'm guessing you do.  If you do put in FET drivers, the capacitance is necessary.

Comment: The more I think about it, this gate driver has been giving me hell from day 1. The output currents are only 0.25A, and that is across the entire product line, so one would think its suitable to drive a simple FET. I have low ESR 0.1, 2.2, 10 and 47uF caps at the VCC pin of the driver.  I will try one more board with TI UCC27714 drivers, however the downside is I need additional overlap protection. Cheers!